# C++ exceptions not caught on Solaris 10 when compiled w/ g++ 5.4 on Solaris 11

Tags: c++, exception, g++, solaris

I'm compiling with g++ 5.4 on Solaris 11 and running on Solaris 10. Everything seems to work except C++ exceptions which aren't caught.

On Solaris 11:

Here are my compiler and OS versions:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS tf-vdevmcps11-d001 5.11 11.3 i86pc i386 i86pc
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

A simple test program.

> $ cat foo.cxx

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        try {
                throw 15; // f();
                std::cout << "after f\n";
        } catch (int i) {
                std::cout << "caught " << i << '\n';
        } catch (...) {
                std::cout << "caught unknown exception\n";
        }
}
```

It compiles and runs properly here:

```
$ g++ -fabi-version=2 -Wabi -o foo -g -m32 foo.cxx
$ ./foo
caught 15
```

These are the dynamic libraries it uses:

```
$ ldd foo
        libstdc++.so.6 =>        /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
```

On Solaris 10 it crashes:

```
$ ./foo
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Abort(coredump)
```

Here's the stack trace of the core file

```
$ pstack core
core 'core' of 10550:   ./foo
 fecca427 _lwp_kill (1, 6) + 7
 fec720c3 raise    (6) + 1f
 fec51d2d abort    (feffdd68, 9844246, 806ac20, fed40c10, 0, 0) + cd
 fef24565 _ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv (0, feff0488, fef211cb, fef65e28, 8066240, 8047c30) + 175
 fef211d7 _ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE (fef243f0, 0, fef21235, fef21267, fef21259, fef65e28) + 17
 fef21270 _ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE (8066240, feff0488, fef21235, fef214cf, feffb818, 8047b6c)
 fef214fe ???????? (8066260, 8061740, 0, fed32a40, 8047b80, fefcab34)
 08051239 main     (8051379, feffb818, 8047ba4, 8051053, 1, 8047bb0) + 35
 08051053 _start   (1, 8047c98, 0, 8047c9e, 8047ca6, 8047cad) + 83
```

Here are the dynamic libraries:

```
$ ldd foo
        libstdc++.so.6 =>        /opt/csw/lib/libstdc++.so.6
        libm.so.2 =>     /usr/lib/libm.so.2
        librt.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/librt.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /opt/csw/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libaio.so.1
        libmd.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libmd.so.1
```

The two GNU libraries are from 5.5 versions of the package:

```
>$ pkginfo -l CSWlibgcc-s1 CSWlibstdc++6
   PKGINST:  CSWlibgcc-s1
      NAME:  libgcc_s1 - The GNU Compiler Collection, libgcc_s.so.1
  CATEGORY:  application
      ARCH:  i386
   VERSION:  5.5.0,REV=2017.10.23
   BASEDIR:  /
    VENDOR:  http://gcc.gnu.org packaged for CSW by Dagobert Michelsen
    PSTAMP:  dam@unstable10x-20171023221120
  INSTDATE:  Apr 22 2019 08:14
   HOTLINE:  http://www.opencsw.org/bugtrack/
     EMAIL:  dam@opencsw.org
    STATUS:  completely installed
     FILES:        4 installed pathnames
                   1 directories
                1883 blocks used (approx)

   PKGINST:  CSWlibstdc++6
      NAME:  libstdc++6 - The GNU Compiler Collection, libstdc++.so.6
  CATEGORY:  application
      ARCH:  i386
   VERSION:  5.5.0,REV=2017.10.23
   BASEDIR:  /
    VENDOR:  http://gcc.gnu.org packaged for CSW by Dagobert Michelsen
    PSTAMP:  dam@unstable10x-20171023221408
  INSTDATE:  Apr 22 2019 08:06
   HOTLINE:  http://www.opencsw.org/bugtrack/
     EMAIL:  dam@opencsw.org
    STATUS:  completely installed
     FILES:        6 installed pathnames
                   1 directories
                   2 executables
               43873 blocks used (approx)
```

Comment: At least no repro here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e73080a33007731a

Comment: Pehaps `-fexceptions` is needed? Can you try with `-fabi-version=9` too?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ted. I tried with both -fexceptions and -fabi-version=9 and got the same results.

 πάντα ῥεῖ which OS version did you run it on? Which did you compile on.

Comment: On the second machine the runtime linking finds various libraries (libstdc++, libc, libgcc_s) that might be from different compiler versions than the first machine... you could try statically linking the binary,  or deploying all dependent SOs

Comment: Compiling on Solaris 11 and expecting your application to run on Solaris 10 isn't going to work well.  If you compiled on Red Hat 7, would you expect it to run on Red Hat 6?  You'd be lucky if you could get a simple basic C application to work.  C++, with all its dependent libraries, is going to be much, much more difficult if not impossible. You can't statically link `libc` and most other OS-supplied libraries on Solaris. Compiling on Solaris 10 for deployment on Solaris 11 **does** work reliably, though.

Comment: (cont) See this Oracle discussion group thread:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2193106  Since you can't statically link `libc`, yet `libc` can play a part in exception handling, there may very well be fundamentally-unsolvable problems trying to run a C++ binary on Solaris 10 that was compiled on Solaris 11.